# Error when trying to update data from a datagridview with a textboxes and a button

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, textbox

Im trying to update from a datagridview as well as my database using a couple of textboxes. It works when I try to update ID_vozila and datum_nakupa but it gives me errors when im trying to update id_prodaje,id_prodajalna and id_kupec.

The error says :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Prodaja__ID_kupc__1920BF5C". The conflict occurred in database "C:\USERS\UPORABNIK\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2013\PROJECTS\NALOGA\NALOGA\BIN\DEBUG\PRODAJA.MDF", table "dbo.Kupec", column 'ID_kupca'.

This is the code that runs when a button gets pressed.

```
int selectedIndex = prodajaDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index;

            int rowID = int.Parse(prodajaDataGridView[0, selectedIndex].Value.ToString());

            string query = "Update Prodaja set ID_prodajalca = @Prodajalec, ID_prodajalne = @Prodajalna, ID_kupca = @Kupec, ID_vozila = @Vozilo, Datum_nakupa = @DatumNakupa where ID_prodaje="+rowID;

            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {

                connection.Open();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prodajalec", iD_prodajalcaTextBox.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prodajalna", iD_prodajalneTextBox.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kupec", iD_kupcaTextBox.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vozilo", iD_vozilaTextBox.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatumNakupa", datum_nakupaDateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd").Replace(" ", ""));
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();



            }
```

Theres anotother id in the database that has identity set and all the ids have identitty set as well.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: ID_kupca  refers table "dbo.Kupec". Value which you are trying to pass does not exist in the table. Can you check do you have the value in Kupec table? If such value does not exist and you try to update then you would get this error

Comment: Well the problem is that it is in the table. For now i have ids from 1 to 3 and I get this error if I try to update anyone of them

Answer (score 0):

the problem is from your **database side in relations**
you need check your key and FOREIGN key  you cant change a FOREIGN key is not at the master table

Comment: I only used foreign keys that are in the tables

Comment: whatch this table table "dbo.Kupec", column 'ID_kupca' sure the key not at there

Comment: There are 3 rows in kupec and they all have 'ID_kupca' but those ids dont work in the program.

Comment: the error is from your db i suggest you use break point and get string send to db and debug it in your db you will see what is the error exactly